# why it gives me weird result for XmlHttpRequest object?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following code to get read the xml

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
           alert(xmlhttp);
            var xmlDoc;
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
             alert(xmlDoc);
            }
           alert(xmlDoc);
```

what weird i see is xmlHttp reads the XML, but xmlDoc comes undefined as an error.
While when i apply the debugger and trace it, in that case xmlDoc doesn't come undefined. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, an `ajax` request (**Asynchronous** Javascript and XML) is asynchronous.

That means, you're accessing the `xmlhttp` variable too early. It doesn't have readyState===4 neither does it have status===200 at that point. You need to put that into the `onreadystatechange` handler which fires each time, the ready state changes for the current request.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var xmlDoc;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        alert(xmlDoc);
    }
};
```

Note, the above is a very minimalistic example. In real world code you would need to make a lot more browser dependend stuff (mostly for IE).

Comment: I got some solution that passing third parameter as false does work.

Comment: How can i clear cache in Javascript, because i see xmlHttpRequest persist old values

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: to avoid caching, either use a POST request (those are never get cached) or append some random stuff within the query-string.

Comment: But when i make first parameter POST, then it doesn't even fetch the results.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: a POST request has slightly different call than GET. Check the web/google for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the undefined error comes from the last line of your code, it makes sense as the variable may not be defined as you defined the value of it in the `if` clause.